# prestashop: changes not reflecting immediately

Tags: php, prestashop

I have written a module for prestashop where one can change shop name. And for that my module will replace shop name by using code.

```
Configuration::updateValue('PS_SHOP_NAME',Tools::getvalue('shop_name'));
```

But the problem is when page gets load for first time it still shows the older name. If i reload the page then only it shows new name. Can anyone please help me how to fix this problem?

Comment: Perhaps you need to clean the cache automatically.

Comment: Is there a way to do it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

"nocache" HTML header, maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the module hook is being loaded after the header information is fetched.

Answer (score 0):

Could not found any solution but in the end I had to use

```
 header('Location:'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Obviously this will solve problem. After changing variable it will reload the page from server itself.